# Changing every object in a group

Tags: mesh, groups

I'm asking how to change every object in a group of objects to be the same mesh type as a third object, which is created on a different layer.

Thanks for the answers

Comment: what is a `mesh type` ? do you mean mesh data-block like in duplicates ?

Comment: Yes, I want to change every object in the group so that they are like duplicates of the chosen object.

Comment: is this one time thing or for animation ?

Comment: One time thing. I just want to change them, animate them falling into a box, count the number of intersections and then begin again with other meshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a script :

- set the group name
- select the chosen object and run the script

***Note :*** you can choose to make them linked or non-linked duplicates

```
import bpy

group_name = 'Group'
linked = False   

chosen = bpy.context.object
mygroup = bpy.data.groups[group_name].objects 
for obj in mygroup:
    if linked :
        obj.data = chosen.data        # linked duplicates
    else :
        obj.data = chosen.data.copy() # Non linked duplicates
```

Comment: One more thing. I'm also trying to keep the location of the object by setting the obj.location to a temp value and after copying the data, I set the location back, but it just don't work. What can I do about it?

Comment: make sure the stored value is still valid, (use .copy() to get the value not a pointer ) , do you have constraints or physics ?

Comment: Now I came to another problem. If I copy the data of the objects, somehow, the scaling is not copyed. What can I add to the code to copy also the scaling of the selecdet object?

Comment: @padr add this in the loop `obj.scale = choosen.scale`